# Creating and Selecting Angular Material Tab

Tags: javascript, angularjs, material-design, angular-material

I am currently using the `md-selected` property of the `md-tabs` directive to control which tab is the selected tab. When I create a new tab, I'd like to select the newly created tab. This works in the demo I've included, but throws errors. Is there a better way?

js:

```
$scope.addTab = function (title, view) {
  view = view || title + " Content View";
  var newIndex = tabs.push({ title: title, content: view, disabled: false});
  $scope.selectedIndex = newIndex;
};
```

html:

```
<md-tabs md-selected="selectedIndex" md-border-bottom="">
  <md-tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs" ng-disabled="tab.disabled" label="{{tab.title}}">
```

error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetLeft' of undefined
at updateInkBarStyles (angular-material.js:12808)
at Object.handleSelectedIndexChange [as fn] (angular-material.js:12750)
at Scope.$get.Scope.$digest (angular.js:14308)
at Scope.$get.Scope.$apply (angular.js:14571)
at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> (angular.js:21571)
at HTMLFormElement.eventHandler (angular.js:3032)
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JdbLda

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The major issue I discovered was that your `newIndex` in the add wasn't 0-based, as [push returns the new length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push):

```
var newIndex = tabs.push({ title: title, content: view, disabled: false});
$timeout(function() {
  $scope.selectedIndex = newIndex - 1;
});
```

I wrapped the change in a `$timeout`, otherwise `tabs` hasn't updated yet and throws an undefined error.

I also changed the `previous` and `selected` to just be their respective indices instead of a full tab (You can choose either way, just make sure you know when you're comparing an `int` to a `tab` object!). And, on the first pass, `selected` is `null`:

```
previous = selected || old;
```

You can see the whole thing on this [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eNBMgV)!

Comment: Ah, yea, I messed up the `newIndex` portion of the codepen. I guess wrapping it in the $timeout is the only way to wait for the tabs to be created. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Since this question was posted, they have added the [`md-autoselect`](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdTabs) flag:

> **md-autoselect** *boolean*
>   When present, any tabs added after the initial load will be automatically selected